# Excel update if cells in an area show different status

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I have a column K24-K28 and each cell in it has a data validated dropdown between multiple status "1“ (bad),“2“ (middle) and „3“(fine).

What should be the formula for me to update K23

1. to show “3” if all cells show “3”, maximum 1 cell shows „2“ and no cell shows “1”
2. to show “2” if at least 2 cells show “2” but none “1” regardless how many “3” there are
3. to show “1” if at least 1 cell shows “1” regardless of all other cells?

Comment: You're on the right track with the if-statement tag.  Can you shared what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my answer and then realized you have your data vertically rather than horizontal. Adjust the formulas below to correct that misunderstanding...

You can use a combination of IF and COUNTIF formulas. Adjust the formula to reflect your correct range, but here it is.

Formula for cell A2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,1)>0,1,IF(COUNTIF(B2:F2,2)>1,2,3))
```

Drag it down, and you're done.

Breaking it down:

- First, it's seeing if any cell in the range contains a 1. If so, mark as 1.
- If the first result is false, then it looks to see if more than 1
  cell contains a 2. If so, mark as 2.
- If the second result is false, then mark as 3.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it’s working with adjusted range. You saved my day!